# C#: Giving access to private members without 3-fold code duplication

Tags: c#, private-members

I have a class

```
public class Foo{
    public Foo{...}

    private void someFunction(){...}
    ...
    private Acessor{
        new Acessor
    }
}
```

with some private functionality (someFunction). However, sometimes, I want to allow another class to call Foo.SomeFunction, so I have an inner class access Foo and pass out that:

```
public class Foo{
    public Foo{...}

    private void someFunction(){...}
    ...
    public Acessor{
        Foo _myFoo;
        new Acessor(Foo foo){_myFoo = foo;}
        public void someFunction(){
            _myFoo.someFunction();
        }
    }
}
```

With this code, if I want a Foo to give someone else pemission to call someFunction, Foo can pass out a new Foo.Accessor(this).

Unfortunately, this code allows anyone to create a Foo.Accessor initiated with a Foo, and they can access someFunction! We don't want that. However, if we make Foo.Accessor private, then we can't pass it out of Foo.

My solution right now is to make Acessor a private class and let it implement a public interface IFooAccessor; then, I pass out the Foo.Accessor as an IFooAccessor. This works, but it means that I have to declaration every method that Foo.Accessor uses an extra time in IFooAccessor. Therefore, if I want to refactor the signature of this method (for example, by having someFunction take a parameter), I would need to introduce changes in three places. I've had to do this several times, and it is starting to really bother me. Is there a better way?

Comment: How about `public void SomeFunction()` ?

Comment: Your question looks a bit misled. Are you trying to use private methods for security? If so then that's not quite right, they can still be invoked through Reflection.
If you're looking to replace the "friend" concept from VB - no need, C# works well without it but you may need to reconsider your design.
And when in doubt - make it public. If you're calling it directly through 15 wrappers then there's no need of wrappers

Comment: @Henk Holterman: That would work, except I don't want someFunction to be immediately accessible by everyone any anyone.

Comment: @Sten Petrov: I am trying to encode a behavior be enforced by the type system. I am not using this for security, and I know that Reflection can get around it. What I really want to do is make it difficult for someone to inadverdantly use this code incorrectly; the way I see it, if you are using Reflection and something screws up, you had it coming.

Comment: Can you describe the actual purpose behind this? It still doesn't sound right. If you want to make it difficult to mess things up then you don't expose the method. But if you're still exposing a direct call to it, even through wrappers, then you're not preventing any misuse.
What is the actual application of this method?

Comment: @Sten Petrov 
Here is one context where this has come up for me:

Foo is a Model (in the Model-View-Controller sense of the word). It needs to keep track of a bunch of ModelObjects, so it has an AddObject(ModelObject modelObject) function which lets ModelObject register themselves with the model. I want this function to be acessable to any ModelObject created by the Model, or by an object created by the model (and so on), but not available just by having a reference to the Model (so you can't create a Model and then just register a bunch of things you created with it.)

Comment: You can restructure this by making the function available on ModelObject itself: ModelObject.AddToController(controller)
Then any object created by ModelObject may or may not be given references to the ModelObject that created them or the controller that ModelObject belongs to and thus granted or rejected access to the AddToController method

Comment: @yrudoy - 1) add this kind of info to the question, don't bury it in the comments. 2) I still can't see a reason to break encapsulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer this question, since it's not clear (to me at least) what exactly you want to achieve. (You write `make it difficult for someone to inadverdantly use this code` in a comment).

Maybe, if the method is to be used in a special context only, then explicitly implementing an interface might be what you want:

```
public interface ISomeContract {
    void someFunction();
}

public class Foo : ISomeContract {
    public Foo() {...}

    void ISomeContract.someFunction() {...}
}
```

This would mean, that a client of that class would have to cast it to `ISomeContract` to call `someFunction()`:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var x = foo as ISomeContract;
x.someFunction();
```

Comment: This ins't exactly what I am looking for, but I think it might work. I'm going to accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If someFunction has to be accessible for classes in the same assembly, use internal instead of private modifier.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b(v=vs.71).aspx

If it has to be accessible for classes which are not in the same assemble then, it should be public. But, if it will be used by just a few classes in other assemblies, you probably should think better how you are organizing you code.

Comment: In my case, I don't want someFunction to be accessible to everything in the same assembly, so unfortunately I cannot do that...

Comment: probably you have to organize better your code. I mean, most of the times we found this kind of problems it is because we have a design problem or packaging problem.

Comment: Another way between `internal` and `public` would be to use the [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) to give access to some internal methods only to specific other assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. A class that was simple, elegant and easy to understand, except for one ugly method that had to be called in one layer, that was not supposed to be called further down the food chain. Especially not by the consumers of this class.

What I ended up doing was to create an extension on my base class in a separate namespace that the normal callers of my classes would not be using. As my method needed private access this was combined with explicit interface implementation shown by M4N.

```
namespace MyProject.Whatever
{
    internal interface IHidden
    {
        void Manipulate();
    }

    internal class MyClass : IHidden
    {
        private string privateMember = "World!";

        public void SayHello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello " + privateMember);
        }

        void IHidden.Manipulate()
        {
            privateMember = "Universe!";
        }
    }
}

namespace MyProject.Whatever.Manipulatable
{
    static class MyClassExtension
    {
        public static void Manipulate(this MyClass instance)
        {
            ((IHidden)instance).Manipulate();
        }    
    }
}
```